# css position sticky wont stay at top

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm having this strange behaviour, when i scroll down yellow box goes on top of blue box, i have set position sticky to both yellow box and blue box so when i scroll down those two should stay there and should not go on top of another. When i scroll down blue and yellow box should stay but only orange box should be scrollable, any help ?

[image]

code to try:

https://codesandbox.io/s/example-react-hooks-usestate-forked-69suro?file=/src/index.js

code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./app.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="box"></div>
      <div className="both">
        <div className="left__side"></div>
        <div className="right__side">
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
          <div className="oikea__box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.both {
  display: flex;
}

.left__side {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.right__side {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2px;
}

.oikea__box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `.left__side` selector has a top of `0px`. This should be the height of the container above it - in this case 100px.

Comment: how do you know its 100 ?

Comment: You have `height` in the `.box` selector as `100px`. By making the `top` of `.left__side` 100px, it will not sit above `.box`.

Answer (score 1):

for yellow box you cannot put top:0 bcs it will stay 0px from top, if u want to put it under blue box, u can put top: (blue height in px) which is 100px.

```
.left__side: {
top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
top: 100px;
```

For .left__side in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

Your "both" class is overlap with the blue box. You don't need to put "sticky" to the yellow box because flex will put yellow box position after blue box.

Try this:

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.both {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.left__side {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right__side {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.oikea__box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
}
```